# macOS Calendar shows time of events from Exchange off by one hour during DST switchover

Tags: macos, calendar, exchange

I've been having persistent issues with events from my Office365 calendar showing at the wrong time in the macOS native calendar app.

They are always off by an hour, and this only occurs during the time period when the USA has switched to daylight savings time but the UK (where I'm based) hasn't - or vice versa. So it happens twice a year for a period of 3 or 4 weeks in March / October. I think it probably only affects events scheduled using a USA timezone that follows DST.

The issue doesn't seem to affect calendars from google accounts, only those from 'Exchange' accounts.

The events show at the correct time on both iPhone's built in Calendar (setup via the native iOS exchange connection) and on the Office 365 calendar website.

Timezone in system settings app is automatically selected and shows as "Greenwich Mean Time" which is currently correct. I'm using macOS Sonoma (14.4). I have timezone support enabled in macOS calendar and fully understand the impact that scheduling events in other timezones that observe different DST changeovers ***should*** have.